Uniform Convergence of Integrable Functions and Counterexamples
Let $ \{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a sequence of real-valued integrable functions on $ X $ such that
$
\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 0 \quad \text{as } n \to \infty
$
(that is, $ f_n $ converges to $ f $ uniformly on  $X$ ). Then $ f$  is integrable and
$
\int_X f_n \, d\mu \to \int_X f \, d\mu \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$
Give an example that shows that the claim can fail.
Maybe this statement will fail when $\mu(X)=\infty$, but I can not construct one.

Have you tried anything? There is a  very simple counterexample.

Choose for instance $f_n$ such that $\int f_n=1$ and $f_n \to 0$ uniformly

Now that the question itself is sensible, you should include your attempts.  Even failed attempts along with some analysis showing why they aren't counterexamples are worthwhile.  As a hint, the claim has the form "$p$ and $q$".  There are counterexamples where $p$ holds and $q$ doesn't, where $p$ doesn't and $q$ does (this one requires interpreting the convergence "correctly"), and where both $p$ and $q$ fail to hold.  Any would satisfy your question.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Define $$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\cdot 1_{(k,k+1]}(x), \ \ \ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\cdot 1_{(k,k+1]}(x)$$
where $1_{(k,k+1]}$ is the indicator function of $(k,k+1]$.
Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$ (since $|f_n-f| \le \frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n$). Further each $f_n$ is integrable with $\int_X f_n\mathrm{d}\mu = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ while $f$ is not integrable since $\int_X f\mathrm{d}\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty$.
